# Solving an ODE from many starting points

Tags: ode

I have a situation where I'm interested in solving the same ODE many times, from different initial locations. More precisely, I'm interested in solving an ODE of the form

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= f(x) \\
x(0) &= a \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}

where I know that this ODE has a $T$-periodic orbit $\mathcal{A}$, i.e for $a \in \mathcal{A}$, we have that

\begin{align}
x(0) &= a \implies x(T) = a
\end{align}

My problem is such that at each iteration $k$, I am given a point $a_k \in \mathcal{A}$, and need to output where the ODE takes $a_k$ after time $t$, i.e.

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= f(x) \\
x(0) &= a_k \\
\implies b_k &\triangleq x(t)
\end{align}

and I want to report $b_k$.

My question is: is there a better way of doing this than using an ODE solver at every step $k$? For example, if possible, I would prefer to incur a one-off cost at the start of my algorithm which allows me to map directly from $a_k$ to $b_k$, rather than having to repeatedly solve the same problem.

**Additional details**:

The system I'm interested in is a two-dimensional Hamiltonian system, given in coordinates as

\begin{align}
\frac{dq}{dt} &= |p|^{\alpha - 1} \cdot \text{sign} (p) \\
\frac{dp}{dt} &= -|q|^{\beta - 1} \cdot \text{sign} (q)
\end{align}

where $\alpha, \beta > 1$ such that $1/\alpha + 1/\beta = 1$.

The standard integrator for such systems is the leapfrog integrator, which I would use if I was solving for a single trajectory. As written, the system is non-smooth - I would rather not worry about that right now, and if it makes the question easier to answer, please feel free to assume that everything involved *is* smooth.

When $\alpha = \beta = 2$ things are much easier, and I can handle this situation fine - I'm asking about the other cases.

Comment: Is your right-hand-side always the same?

Comment: @nicoguaro Yep! Just the starting point changes. Even the amount of time I want to solve the equations over is constant.

Comment: I just realized that you equation is nonlinear. Do you have the form of $f(x)$?

Comment: @nicoguaro explained more at bottom of post

Comment: Since all your starting points lie on the same orbit, can't you just compute one orbit and interpolate to get all the values you need?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I'd be happy to do that if someone could outline how to implement this efficiently. I thought about a similar idea previously but got stuck because I wanted to avoid projecting my $a$ onto the computed orbit - I could certainly believe there's a better way, though, and I'd love to hear it if so.

Comment: When interpolating among pre-computed values, you have to be careful to preserve the Hamiltonian structure. For example, when interpolating points on a circle, you are approximating pieces of a circle with its chord. Your case, $p = q = 2$, yields a rotation. Plain interpolation could place you on the "chord". One example of interpolation is discussed here http://doi.org/10.1002/nme.2681